# Standardising point size across groups

Tags: r, leaflet, point, r-mapview

Using `zcol`, `cex` and `burst` it is possible to adjust the size of all levels within a point layer in `mapview`. However, the size of each point is relative only to the size of other points WITHIN that same level. For example, in the following code, the size of a point with `number.of.types` value 14 in group `a` is the same as `number.of.types` value 6 in group `b`.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(tidyr)
library(mapview)

b = breweries %>% 
  drop_na(number.of.types) %>% 
  mutate(group = ifelse(number.of.types >= 7,"a","b"))

b %>%
  mapview(zcol="group", cex="number.of.types", burst=T)
```

Is it possible to standardise the size of points across levels without resorting to having to define this for each layer level individually?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**update**

I just discovered that setting the `burst`-argument to `FALSE` seems to do the trick?

```
b %>%
  mapview(zcol="group", cex="number.of.types", burst=FALSE)
```

[image]

**previous answer**

I'm not sure about `mapview`-options, since I rarely use the function.

You could try reprocuding the map you desire with leaflet (which is what mapview uses if I remember correctly).

It requires a bit more lines of code though..

```
library(leaflet)

colorGroup <- colorFactor( topo.colors( 2 ), b$group )

leaflet() %>% addTiles() %>%
  addCircleMarkers( data  = b,
                    #circle size
                    radius  = ~number.of.types,
                    #circle borders
                    color = "black", opacity = 1, stroke = TRUE, weight = 2,
                    #circle inside
                    fillColor = ~ colorGroup( group ), fillOpacity = 0.8 )
```

results in

[image]

And you would have to add code for legend and popups (if needed).